# Don´t find html text with python re.findall

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I can't find html text containing `&shy;`. At least I think this could be the reason because other search patterns are working.

I am using `re.findall` in Python. The following is shortened:

```py
findthis = '<span class="sr-only-xs">Nieder&shy;schlags&shy;wahr&shy;schein&shy;lich&shy;keit: </span>.\d+%'

list = [findall(searchthis, webpage, re.DOTALL)]
```

This is what I want to find:

```html
<span class="sr-only-xs">Nieder&shy;schlags&shy;wahr&shy;schein&shy;lich&shy;keit: </span>
0%
```

Error is "list index out of range" because the list is empty.

Comment: try replace the `&` with `&amp;`. it may be that it is being converted.

Comment: you should check if list not empty before youtry to get something from list.